# Install iOS ipa on only specific devices

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ipa

How can we install the ipa of our iOS app on only specific devices based on the unique identification number of the mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/

And than ADD devices UDID in the "Devices" Menu

Than after In the "Provisioning Profiles" Menu, click on "Development" -> select the profile -> "Edit" -> Scroll down, activate the devices you added

And you can share your app by TestFlight or https://www.diawi.com/

now app is only install on register.